# ubuntu 12.1-unable to mount location

Tags: mount

There are two HDD (sda and sdb) on my computer. I installed ubuntu 12.1 on "`sda`". And I mounted to `/home` "`sdb`". Desktop-->above menu bar-->**Go-->Computer**-->2.0 TB Hard Disk(sdb)-->Unable to mount location.
I want to access "2.0 TB Hard Disk(sdb)" from there (Go-->Computer). How can I mount it?

```
physics@physics:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdb5
mount: /dev/sdb5 already mounted or /home busy
mount: according to mtab, /dev/sdb5 is already mounted on /home
```

I typed `fdisk -l` on terminal:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 256.1 GB, 256060514304 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 31130 cylinders, total 500118192 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000072a0

Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System
/dev/sda1 * 2048 480585727 240291840 83 Linux
/dev/sda2 480587774 500117503 9764865 5 Extended
/dev/sda5 480587776 500117503 9764864 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0001ca53

Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System
/dev/sdb1 2046 3907028991 1953513473 5 Extended
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sdb5 2048 3907028991 1953513472 83 Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

Unmount the /dev/sdb5 and mount it inside a directory in `/media` so that the drive appears on the unity bar.

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb5
```

create a directory inside `/media` folder by running below commands,

```
cd /media
mkdir hdd
```

Then mount the `dev/sdb5` in the hdd directory by running the below command,

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb5 /media/hdd
```

You can't able to delete the files inside /dev/sdb5,because it was your `/home` partition.

Comment: physics@physics:~$ sudo umount /dev/sdb5
umount: /home: device is busy.
        (In some cases useful info about processes that use
         the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))

Comment: sudo umount -l /dev/sdb5

Comment: you can't unmount sdb5 because it is your home partition.plz explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Firstly Avinash thanks for your helps.
sudo umount -l /dev/sdb5
cd /media
mkdir hdd
sudo mount /dev/sdb5 /media/hdd
I solved the problem using above commands.
But there are two folder in sdb5, named "physics" and "last+found". I dont want to any files related to ubuntu there. I will use as a "program store" it. it must include anything about ubuntu. But I should be able to access it.

Comment: yes you can store the files inside  that and you can be able to access that.

Comment: I dont want to any files related to ubuntu there (sdb5). That is, it must empty. How can I achieve it?

Comment: what are the files and folders inside sda5?.

Comment: there are two folder in sdb5, named "physics" and "last+found"

Comment: i think your physics folder contains document,downlods,etc as sub-folders.am i correct?

Comment: yes you are correct.

Comment: don't delete that.upload the screenshot of gparted /dev/sdb,i will help you to create new partition for storing files.

Comment: Thanks. I can reinstall the ubuntu. No problem. if I reinstall it, how should I partition sdb5 ( which ones /home, /bot ...).

Comment: I will use it for storing files.

Comment: If you reinstall ubuntu,don't create a seperate partition for /boot,/home put all in the single ext4 partition.

Comment: upload the gparted sdb5 screenshot,you don't need to reinstall ubuntu.

Comment: but I have two HDD, sda and sdb. I want to use sdb for storing files.

Comment: first delete the sdb using gparted in the ubuntu-live disk.Then reinstall ubuntu on the sda not sdb.If i had the sda and sdb screenshot,i will explain you clearly.

Comment: I will try it. You will write the result I get.

Comment: what result you get?

Comment: sorry. I will write the result I get after reinstall.

Comment: what should I select for "mount point"? in sdb.

Comment: did you trying to set the mount point for which partition?

Comment: I will reinstall the ubuntu on sda "fisrt HDD", I need to select a mount point for sdb "second HDD"?

Comment: what are the options available?

Comment: give it as /media

Comment: The problem is solved. Please see http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2194695&page=2

Comment: you are asking the mountpoint for your dev/sdb during installation,how the above answer related to that.